# Next Prime number Java only working with certain numbers

Tags: java, primes

This function its only working for certain numbers, but for 15, or 5 it does not give me correct next prime.

```
public static int nextPrime(int n) {
    boolean isPrime = false;
    int m = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
    int start = 3;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        n = n + 1;
    }
    while (!isPrime) {
        isPrime = true;
        for (int i = start; i <= m; i = i + 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isPrime) {
            n = n + 2;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me, for 15 and 5.

Comment: Try using longer names for your variables, it makes the code more readable and easier to answer. `i` to `potentialFactor`, `m` to `maxFactor`

Comment: can you provide inputs & expected outputs?

Comment: Holy crap you should submit this to CodeReview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go upto  sqrt(n), you need to go upto sqrt(number) that you are evaluating

for example consider you pass n = 5

it will start loop from 3 and it will end the loop at 4 that is not what you need to find next prime number

outer loop
start from n + 1 until you find prime
inner loop
you should start from 3 and sqrt(numberUnderIteration)

Comment: This should be a comment. Unless you expand upon it.

Comment: @user see the explained version

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your boundary at the square root of the *original number* only. In order for you to check if every next number works, you need to recalculate the boundary whenever the `n` value is changed. So, put `int m = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));` inside of your while loop.

You also need to increment `n` by 1 before you start any calculations, or it will accept `n` itself as a prime number if it is one. For example, `nextPrime(5)` would return `5` because it passes the conditions.

And finally, you don't need to increment `n` by 2 at the end of your while loop because if you are on an even number, it will break out (keep adding 2 to an even number will always be even). I've commented the part of your code that I changed:

```
public static int nextPrime(int n) {
    boolean isPrime = false;

    int start = 2; // start at 2 and omit your if statement

    while (!isPrime) {
        // always incrememnt n at the beginning to check a new number
        n += 1;
        // redefine max boundary here
        int m = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));

        isPrime = true;
        // increment i by 1, not 2 (you're skipping numbers...)
        for (int i = start; i <= m; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            } 
        }
        // you don't need your "if (!isPrime)..." because you always increment
    }
    return n;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(nextPrime(15)); // 17
    System.out.println(nextPrime(5)); // 7
    System.out.println(nextPrime(8)); // 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute m inside the for loop.

```
  while (!isPrime) {
     isPrime = true;
      int m = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));

     // do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine except when a prime number is given as input, your method returns input itself.

Example if `5` is your input `nextPrime(5)` returns `5`. If you want 7 (next prime number after 5) to be returned in this case.

Just add `n=n+1;` at the start of your method. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I coded a quick `Prime` class that tracks known primes, giving a huge performance boost to finding multiple large primes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Primes {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static int nextPrime(int number){

        //start it off with the basic primes
        if(primes.size() == 0){
            primes.add(2);
            primes.add(3);
            primes.add(5);
            primes.add(7);
        }

        int idx = primes.size()-1;
        int last = primes.get(idx);

        //check if we already have the prime we are looking for
        if(last > number){
            //go to the correct prime and return it
            boolean high = false;
            boolean low = false;
            int prevIdx = 0;
            int spread = 0;
            //keep finagling the index until we're not high or low
            while((high = primes.get(idx-1) > number) || (low = primes.get(idx) <= number)){
                spread = Math.abs(prevIdx-idx);
                //because we always need to move by at least 1 or we will get stuck
                spread = spread < 2 ? 2: spread;
                prevIdx = idx;
                if(high){
                    idx -= spread/2;
                } else if(low){
                    idx += spread/2;
                }
            };
            return primes.get(idx);
        }

        /*FIND OUR NEXT SERIES OF PRIMES*/

        //just in case 'number' was prime
        number++;

        int newPrime = last;
        //just keep adding primes until we find the right one
        while((last = primes.get(primes.size()-1)) < number){
            //here we find the next number
            newPrime += 2;
            //start with the assumption that we have a prime, then try to disprove that
            boolean isPrime = true;
            idx = 0;
            int comparisonPrime;
            int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(newPrime);
            //make sure we haven't gone over the square root limit- also use post-increment so that we use the idx 0
            while((comparisonPrime = primes.get(idx++)) <= sqrt){
                if(newPrime % comparisonPrime == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime){
                primes.add(newPrime);
            }
        }

        return last;
    }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        long start;
        long end;
        int prime;
        int number;

        number = 1000000;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prime = Primes.nextPrime(number);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Prime after "+number+" is "+prime+". Took "+(end-start)+" milliseconds.");

        number = 500;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prime = Primes.nextPrime(number);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Prime after "+number+" is "+prime+". Took "+(end-start)+" milliseconds.");  

        number = 1100000;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prime = Primes.nextPrime(number);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Prime after "+number+" is "+prime+". Took "+(end-start)+" milliseconds.");      
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Prime after 1000000 is 1000003. Took 384 milliseconds.
Prime after 500 is 503. Took 10 milliseconds.
Prime after 1100000 is 1100009. Took 65 milliseconds.
```

As you can see, this takes a long time the first iteration, but we only have to perform that operation once. After that, our time is cut down to almost nothing for primes less than our first number (since it's just a lookup), and it is very fast for primes that are just a bit bigger than our first one (since we have already done most of the work).

EDIT: Updated search for existing primes using a variation on a `Binary Search Algorithm`. It cut the search time at least in half.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Testing 
{
    public static void main(String Ar[])
    {
        int a = 0, i, j;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in.nextInt();
        for (j = a + 1;; j++) 
        {
            for (i = 2; i < j; i++) 
            {
                if (j % i == 0)
                break;
            }
              if (i == j) 
             {
                 System.out.println(j);
                 break;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect code for finding next prime for a given number.

```
public class NextPrime
{

    int nextPrime(int x)
    {
        int num=x,j;
            for( j=num+1;;j++)
            {
                int count=0;

                    for(int i=1;i<=j;i++)
                    {
                        if(j%i==0)
                        {
                        count++;
                        //System.out.println("entered");
                        }
                        //System.out.println(count);
                    }
                    if(count==2)
                    {
                    System.out.println(" next prime is ");
                    break;
                    }

            }return j;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        NextPrime np = new NextPrime();
        int nxtprm = np.nextPrime(9);
        System.out.println(nxtprm);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I hope the following code works exactly.


import java.util.Scanner;
public class NextPrime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer number : ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int x = n + 1;; x++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int i = 2; i < x / 2; i++) {
                if (x % i == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                System.out.println("Next prime is : " + x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```