# Printing a triangle of prime numbers using for loop

Tags: java, loops, primes

I am trying to make a triangle of prime numbers .. the number of rows will be user defined 
for example if user gives "4" as number of rows then the program should show a triangle of prime numbers containing 4 rows

```
input :4

output : 

2
3 5
7 11 13
17 19 23 29
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You should have mentioned, "Please help me in doing homework!"

Comment: I suggest you first write a program to print the first `n` primes. Then write a program to output a triangle of `X`s. You will then have learnt enough to put them together. (I assume your class has covered all the basics you need to know).

Comment: Also you forgot to include your attempts to solve this problem. Without it it looks like you are trying to cheat by asking us to do your homework, instead of looking for guidance by asking what you did wrong while trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @slim i have tried many patterns , i am practicing loops and i am new to programming i know how to print the pattern of normal numbers and how to print primes but when i tried doing both together it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two tasks: get the list of primes (or just something like `nextPrime(int)`) and get the triangle, both are very simple.

For the implementation of first, you may look at [Next Prime number Java only working with certain numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082770/next-prime-number-java-only-working-with-certain-numbers)

For the implementation of second, just do something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        nextPrime = ...
        System.out.print (nextPrime + " ");
    }
    System.out.println ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you already have your primes (sufficient amount).

```
int[] primes = ...;
```

Then for N strings create array is StringBuilders and fill them up with your numbers:

```
StringBuilder[] builders = new StringBuilder[N];
int count = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
    int size = row + 1;
    builders[row] = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        builders[row].append(primes[count++]);
        builders[row].append(' ');
    }
}
```

And then you may print them

```
for(StringBuilder sb : builders) 
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//please try these
import java.util.*;
public class primePtt1
{
public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int num) {
   int c=0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0)
         c++;
   }
   if (c==2)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter no. of rows : ");
        int rows = sc.nextInt();
        int counter = 2;    
         for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
         for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       /* Try to find next prime number by incrementing counter and testing it for primality */
        while(!isPrimeNumber(counter)){
            counter++;
            }
        System.out.print(counter+" ");
        counter++;
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

}
}
```